# Detect moving direction (clockwise or counterclockwise) between 2 points in a circle with shortest distance

Tags: direction

I have a problem: There are `n` milestones in a circle stored in an `int` array `(0..n-1)`.  Given two milestones `x`, and `y`, I need to determine the shortest distance between them; either clockwise or counterclockwise.

Below is a link including an image that illustrates an example of the problem with `n = 20` (I am sorry, I can't upload the image directly because I do not have enough reputation).

http://upanh.biz/images/2014/02/16/circle.png

Assuming: move from 18 -> 1: shortest distance = 3, direction: clockwise.

Thank you in advance and your comments are most welcome.

Comment: Why do the milestones need to be stored in an array?  The diagram indicates that each milestone's value is equal to its index.  Also, do you have a particular programming language in mind?  How have you approached this problem so far?

Comment: If you know the center of the circle, you can derive an angle for each milestone. Then you can simply subtract the angles mod 360 degrees to determine which way is faster. Greater than 180 degrees is one way. Less than 180 degrees is the other. Exactly 180 degrees they are the same. Alternatively, if the milestones are equally spaced and indexed as in the illustration, just do a similar thing with the index values.

Answer (score 0):

It should be pretty straightforward:

```
counterDistance = x < y ? (N - y + x) : (x - y); 
direction = counterDistance < N / 2 ? "counter" : "clock";
```

Comment: @Razwan This will give the correct direction, but not the shortest distance when the direction is clockwise.

Comment: Yes, I agree. That's why I check the distance against N / 2 - if it's greater than N / 2, then it means that there is a shorter distance (the clockwise distance).

Comment: @Razwan: Thank you for helping me. I think you find the shortest distance out correctly but I don't understand your direction.
For example: N = 20 as the image above.
I move from 18 -> 1: distance = 3 < 20/2 but direction should be: clockwise.

Comment: No, when `x = 18`, `y = 1`, `distance = 18 < 1 ? (N - 1 - 18) : (18 - 1) = 18 - 1 = 17` (because `18 < 1` evaluates as false). So direction becomes `clock`. I will rename the `distance` variable to `counterDistance` just to make it more clear.

Comment: I understand your solution. It helps me resolve another bigger problem .